# Show dates between now and 4 weeks later

Tags: php, mysql, forms, loops

How to select dates from mysql table 'Courses' between now and 4 weeks later where Open='1' and sort by Date and Time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Courses 
WHERE Open='1' AND Date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 WEEK 
ORDER BY Date, Time
```

Not tested